# Ensure type safety with Java generics

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

I am trying to improve the type safety of the following method:

```
A<String> method(B<String> arg);
```

How do I make sure that this method is not called with a raw type `B` and that compiler always checks for String type specified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't prevent someone from calling a method with a raw type.

The reason is for backward compatibility with pre-generic versions of java.

Answer (score 1):

If the compiler warnings are turned on (`-Xlint:unchecked`), you will get a warning if that method is called with a raw type:

> warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion A a = method(new B());